# WebRTC - using relay server when firewall prevent p2p connection (TURN/STUN)

Tags: video-streaming, html5-video, webrtc

How can I use some kind of web server to relay WebRTC video calls using port 80 or 443?
I'm looking for a solution to do this:
Client A (getUserMedia()) => My server via port 80/443 => Client B
Thanks!

======
EDIT: I understand the solution might be STUN/TURN server, but I don't seem to find any suitable solution which is easy and well documented. 
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Use an Ingate E-SBC which has TURN service built in specifically designed for this.